# Why do print and f-string perform evaluation at different times?

Tags: python, f-string

Does the evaluation of variables in `print` and f-string happen at different times?

I expected it to be the same output for both.

```
def foo(x):
    x.append([5])
    return x

y, z = [1], [3]
print('y:', y, 'z:', z)
# y: [1] z: [3]

print('y:', y, 'str(y):', str(y), 'foo(y):', foo(y))  
# y: [1, [5]] str(y): [1] foo(y): [1, [5]]

print(f'z: {z} foo(z): {foo(z)} z: {z}')
# z: [3] foo(z): [3, [5]] z: [3, [5]]
```

Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: Note that a format string will give you the same output as multiple args to `print`: `print('y: {} str(y): {} foo(y): {}'.format(y, str(y), foo(y)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, the expressions are evaluated left-to-right.  In the f-string case, each is converted (with `str`) **immediately** after evaluation, but in the case of `print` (which is a normal function call), all of them are evaluated (and so `y` is mutated) **before** any of them are converted to strings inside `print`.  Explicitly writing `str(y)` in the call to `print` will produce the same results.